# QStandardItemModel inside Qtableview

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I am using `QStandardItemModel` inside `QTableView`. Here i have two button & `Qtableview` inside my mainwindow.
I need only 4 columns inside this. And rows will vary. The two Buttons will be used to add/delete a row (test case).

1. `setHorizontalHeaderItem` is not showing all the text(means all text is not visible). Example if i put `'Text for the Employee Name'` it is not fully visible ?
2. How to make `QStandardItemModel` occupy full `QTableview` (`width`). At present it is showing at top left corner ?

How to achieve it?

Code :

```
model= new QStandardItemModel(4, 4);

    for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; ++column) {
            QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("row %0, column %1").arg(row).arg(column));
            model->setItem(row, column, item);
        }
    }

    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(tr("Time")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(tr("Text for the Employee Name")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(tr("Text for the Employee Address")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QStandardItem(tr("Text for the Employee Date of Birth")));

    model->setVerticalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(tr("Test-Case-----1")));
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

or

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the question is already accepted for the answer, my answer may help someone, as the above accepted answer didn't help me.

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(2,3,this);
//----------
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

Comment: this answer did not fulfill the question

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer comes a bit late, but I was just needing to do the same, and figured out a different solution.

To achieve your goal in Qt 4, you need to adjust the settings of the header of your `QTableView`. To do so, first retrieve the header:

```
QHeaderView *header = ui->tableView->horizontalHeader();
```

Next, adjust the resize mode of the individual columns by calling [`QHeaderView::setResizeMode`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode) (the second flavor, which accepts `logicalIndex`):

```
header->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
header->setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
header->setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
header->setResizeMode(3, QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

In the above example, I chose to stretch column 3, but you may choose any of the columns to be in "stretch" mode.

In Qt 5, the call you want is [`QHeaderView::setSectionResizeMode()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode).

Hope this helps you or anybody else seeking a solution to this problem.